# How to get Date and Time from DateTime in AngularJs controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am having datetime available. All I need to extract date in **dd/MM/yyyy** and time in **hh:mm a** format.

I am try below code, but this is not working. What is wrong with the code and How can I achieve the said target?

```
$scope.date = new Date(dateTimeObj).getDate().toLocaleString("dd/MM/yyyy");
$scope.from = new Date(dateTimeObj).getTime().toLocaleString("hh:mm a");
$scope.to = new Date(dateTimeObj).getTime().toLocaleString("hh:mm a");
```

edit: 
I achieved the above functionality using momentjs.

```
$scope.to moment(dateTimeObj).format("HH:mm A");
```

Now I'm facing a different problem. This value is not getting binded to the view. Html is as below.

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="To" ng-model="to" id="to" value="{{to}}">
```

**How can I bind the value of time object with HTML5's time control?**

Comment: Please, this question has been solved dozens of time. Please search before asking.

Comment: @lin: apologies.I'm on a deadline,Sir, I tried  and didn't find any useful link and hence I asked this question.

Comment: Please close / delete this question and check the link I posted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('pageCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope,$filter) {
   var dateStr = '2015-09-21 18:30:00';
   $scope.dt = $filter('date')(new Date(dateStr.split('-').join('/')), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

{{date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
{{date | date:'hh:mm a'}}

In JS

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aXdMMPmZXtuzTLfX1mXu?p=preview

Comment: By this u will get Current Date and Time in your required Format.